# Select all columns from table group by column

Tags: sql, sql-server

'test_table' contains a column called vendor, with char values from 1 to 9, 1 being highest priority. 'test_table' also has another column named match, with char values either 'I' or 'H', with 'I' receiving higher priority.  I want to return all rows with unique values in ID, prioritized by match, then vendor.

Test_Table

```
ID  Vendor  Match  
 1    3      I  
 1    2      I  
 1    4      H  
 2    1      H  
 2    1      I  
 3    1      H  
 3    2      I
```

Results Desired

```
ID  Vendor  Match   
1     2   I  
2     1   I   
3     2   I  


SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RowNo, * 
     FROM test_table) x
WHERE RowNo = 1 
ORDER BY ID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: If you want to be able to specify the table and column name, you'll have to look at using dynamic SQL. But **first** - read this "must-have-read" article on the topic: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Do you really think its better to create a new table every time that you sp is executed, instead of doing a `SELECT` that doesn't include your `RowNo` column?

Comment: Using the query which you have posted ,try to use CTE and then select the columns except the RowNo which you have defined inside the CTE

Comment: I think you need a better description. Can you show using some sample data how you would return all of the columns but only unique values in one column? If that column has 4 rows where the value is the same, then you only want one row, but which values go in all the other columns?

Comment: Aaron, you are correct, I should have been more specific.  In this scenario, I am not worried about which record is kept.  The values in the other columns are not a concern.  Thank you.

Comment: Praveen, I am not familiar with the usage of CTE, if you could provide an example in the context of my problem I would gladly explore it.  Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have an `ANY` aggregate function, and only in SQL Server 2012 do we have FIRST/LAST-type functionality. So unfortunately, even though you don't care which values from the other rows are chosen, you need to specify somehow. You can say MAX in each column, MIN in each column, both of which can yield values from different source rows, or you can say all the values from the row chosen based on some criteria. You can't just say "I don't care."

Comment: Lamak, I couldn't figure out how to get those results without including the RowNo in my Select LOL, I am open to ideas!

Comment: @Caddy : Here is the query : With CTE as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RowNo, * FROM test_table) Select Col1,Col2,...Coln from CTE where RowNo = 1 Order By ID

Comment: @praveen       Thanks, but is there a way to return all of  test_table's columns without specifying each column name?  If I replace the "Select Col1, Col2 ..." with "Select *" it returns the RowNo column.

Comment: @Caddy : Unfortunately no . There is no way u can do that .If you follow the best practices , you should always specify the  column names instead of * .But there is a way around to achieve this . You can dump the data into a temporary table and then drop the column :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand (or anyone else) I now have a situation where I do indeed care about which row is chosen.  :)  You intimated above that there is a way to get the unique values from one column, while prioritizing other columns in order to get the results you want.  Let's say the above table 'test_table' contains a column called vendor, with char values from 1 to 9, 1 being highest priority.  'test_table' also has another column named match, with char values either 'I' or 'H', with 'I' receiving higher priority.

Comment: Please don't put code, data etc. in a comment. If you have updated requirements, please update the question properly.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry.  Updated the question.

Comment: @praveen Any ideas on the updated question?

Comment: @Caddy: See my ans below

Comment: @praveen Ahhh, thank you so much.  I was trying to place an order by after the From Test_Table.  This is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an order by clause for match column ( character comparison happens based on ascii value)  and another one on vendor column . You can even remove `ascii` keyowrd ( for the sake of clarity i have written) and simply use the column name in order by clause

Try this :

```
 ;With cte as 
  ( 
  Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ascii(match) desc ,vendor )
   AS RowNo,  Id,Vendor ,Match 
  FROM test_table
  )
  Select Id,Vendor,Match from cte
  WHERE RowNo = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id,Vendor,Match
FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,Match Desc,Vendor Asc) AS RowNo, * 
     FROM test_table ) x
WHERE RowNo = 1 
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks vikram and McDowell.  As I was telling praveen, I tried something similar, but had placed my order by in the wrong location.  Thanks so much for your help, truly appreciated.